# при выводе результата пропадает один символ

Tags: c

Необходимо чтобы отфильтровывалось первое слово в строке "__тут будут слова". Важно, в начале стоят два пробела. Сам только начинаю осваивать кодинг, так что не кидайтесь помидорами. При вводе "__тут будет текст" получается "ут", а должно быть "тут". Если отключить start вывод происходит без проблем, но не убираются пробелы перед словом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int start (); //пропускает пробелы в начале строки, проблема именно с ней;
int end (); //удаляет текст после пробела;

int main() //тело
{
    start();
    end();
    return 0;

}

int start() 
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (ch == ' ') ch = '\0';
        else break;
    return 0;
}

int end() 
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n') putchar(ch);
        else break;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша функция `start` считывает символы пока не встретит символ отличный от   (пробел) и после завершает работу. Но она уже считала (и выкинула) символ отличный от   и поэтому у вас пропадает первая буква.

Если вы уберете `start` и замените

```
int end() 
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n') putchar(ch);
        else break;
    return 0;
}
```

на

```
int end() 
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n') putchar(ch);
        else continue;
    return 0;
}
```

то все заработает.

Comment: странно я думал что написал немного по другому. start должна находить пробелы перед словом и удалять их, скажите а как это можно было бы реализовать по другому?
Ваш вариант не помог, так как тогда не получается сделать выборку первого слова((((

Comment: я пояснил, что у вас в коде написано. мой вариант - это ответ на ваш вопрос. в вопросе ничего про следующее слово нет. почитайте вот это [ask] и вот это [tour]

Comment: сори :) не сразу понял суть вашего ответа, говорил что только начинаю изучать кодинг. Спасибо, суть проблемы понял, как решить буду думать.

Comment: но не поленитесь прочитать ссылки, что я дал в предыдущем комментарии